# What type of format is being used?

Tags: json, xml, textmate, dataformat

This is a part of the syntax highlighting code, taken from TextMate.

Do you know what type of `data formatting` is being used? (it's definitely Json-like, but with variations)

```
{   shellVariables = (
        {   name = 'TM_COMMENT_START';
            value = '// ';
        },
        {   name = 'TM_COMMENT_START_2';
            value = '# ';
        },
        {   name = 'TM_COMMENT_START_3';
            value = '/*';
        },
        {   name = 'TM_COMMENT_END_3';
            value = '*/';
        },
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [TextMate manual](http://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars) the grammar definition uses os x properly list format.

Comment: Well, it definitely is NOT a typical `Mac OS X` property list, but by just having a look around I admit I just discovered it MAY have to do with the Property List format being used by NeXTStep... I'll have a look into it.

Comment: Well, it isn't the 'typical' os x property list format, but it is the old-style properly list format (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/OldStylePlists/OldStylePLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001012-BBCBDBJE) with some slight readability modifications.